# Command line bitcoin cash wallet for linux?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, linux

Is there a good command line Bitcoin cash wallet for linux available?

Comment: You may probably try [Sibit](https://www.yegor256.com/2019/05/07/sibit-bitcoin-command-line-client.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bitcoin-ABC or Bitcoin-unlimited, Both are Bitcoin-cash.

after you successsfully install it, you can just send the commands as follows:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "account"
```

to get new bitcoin cash address.

You can find all commands on [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getnewaddress). This documention for Bitcoin core, but as Bitcoin cash is a fork of bitcoin, these commands should work with you. You can find new commands or changes on [Bitcoin-ABC on Github](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getnewaddress)